# How to match a mounted filesystem to a USB device on Linux?

Tags: android, linux, usb, sysfs

What would be the proper way to programatically match from a mounted filesystem to a USB device and 'usbstorage' interface?

I suspect sysfs traversal is the way to go, but sysfs is pretty wild.

Specifically, I have an Android system and my USB stick gets mounted from /dev/block/vold/8:1. (What's that, a volume manager?)

Comment: `match from a mounted filesystem to a USB device` ??? What should that be?

Comment: @greenapps you have a USB storage device (e.g. a USB flash drive) with some partitions carrying some filesystems, and they get mounted somewhere -- so I wanna map from that mount point back to the USB device

Comment: I   understand mounting. I do not understand matching. And have no idea what you mean by mapping back.

Comment: Let's say you have a Linux system with a mounted USB flash drive. I give you the mountpoint, and you have to discover what USB device this mounted filesystem resides on.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Sorry, cannot help you.